# Python regex lookbehind assertion

Tags: python, regex

I want to store a time given in 24 hour format which is part of a string like such:

```
184.107.21.129 - - [03/Feb/2013:02:33:44]
```

My code is

```
times = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?<='+arg+r' - - \[\d{2}/[JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrynlgptvc]/\d{4}:)', new_file.read())
```

where arg is a string "184.107.21.129". new_file is read successfully.
The problem is that the list times is empty upon trying to print it, indicating my regex expression is wrong.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your regex appears to be looking for a colon-delimited sequence of three digit pairs, followed by *no* colon, followed by a date, followed by a colon.  In contrast your example string has the date first, then a colon, then a colon-delimited sequence of three digit pairs, and no trailing colon at the end.

Comment: It should be noted that your regex also matches invalid months, such as `Day`, `Men`, and `Spy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must understand that a lookbehind (or any other assertion) applies from a position in a string and yours is after the time part. Since your lookbehind doesn't contain the time part, it will not work.

In other words, you can write:

```
r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?<='+arg+r' - - \[\d{2}/[JFMASOND][aepuco][brynlgptvc]/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
```

or

```
r'(?<='+arg+r' - - \[\d{2}/[JFMASOND][aepuco][bcglnprtvy]/\d{4}:)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
```

But note that if you only want to extract something with `re.findall` method, you can do it easily with a capture group and without lookarounds:

```
arg+r' - - \[\d{2}/[JFMASOND][aepuco][bcglnprtvy]/\d{4}:(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.